# Don't break good at debug mood

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I call a system assembly and click the 'Break All' (Ctrl+Alt+Break), I expecting to see the fallowing

[image: Expected result]

Instead I get this

[image: Actual result]

What I need to do to get the result from the first image?

Comment: ... because Just My Code enabled.

Comment: @Hamlet I don't want to go in the code of the related assembly - only to debug my code!

Comment: Just try instead of typing posts.

Comment: Tools\Options\Debuggung\General find `Enable Just My Code` and remove check from checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use call stack window and double-click your function there.

Comment: This is not the full answer - but helped me find the problem - I needed to select the thread - http://screencast.com/t/iTY4TC78osAQ

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable "Just My Code" debugging in the settings (as the first line in the second screen points out).

You can even directly disable it a bit lower on that screen. Did you read the entirety of the error message?

Comment: THen do not klick "break all" while it is running in not your code.

Comment: I want so he will break at my code so called they code - as image 1

Comment: break all will break everywhere, just my code enabled will only allow you to break at yours. You cant pick both, either disable just yours, or dont do break all, you cant have both

Comment: In VS 2010 'Break All' breaks all + put the cursor at the current caller - sample 1